# Scraping a database of images with Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm looking for some pointers on scraping a website for images (which may fall beyond my current skill level). I have a database of archival images I'm looking to download (see, e.g., http://digitarq.dgarq.gov.pt/viewer?id=2300366). With each item record there are a collection of TIFF images, which I could download one-by-one by visiting each of the record's images (see the download button on the document viewer).

What I hoped to do was to scrape the item page to find each TIFF image and download them to my local hard drive for research purposes. The difficulty I think I'm running in to is I'm not quite clear how to fetch these download links. The TIFF links along the left side use JavaScript to query the database and pull up a new image. I found it easy enough to start scraping those URLs:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

BASE_URL = "http://digitarq.dgarq.gov.pt"
ITEM_URL = "#{BASE_URL}/viewer?id=2300366"

# Parse the page for items
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(ITEM_URL))

item_id = "2F2603B150884299A0161DCA31F2CA71"
page_items = page.css('#ViewerControl1_UpdatePanelMain #ViewerControl1_divLeftColumn table')

page_items[1..-2].each do |item|
    hrefs = item.css('td a')
    puts hrefs
end
```

The next step is, I think, scraping for the download button, querying the database for the TIFF image, and saving to local. Hypothetically, something like:

```
def scrape_for_download(archive_item)
    archive_item = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL)
    download_item = page.css('#ViewerControl1_HyperLinkDownload')
    download_item.each do |download|
        File.open("#{item}", "w") do |output|
            output.puts output.read
        end
    end
end
```

This is the first scraper I've written where I've had to deal with JavaScript and databases, so it's proving an interesting challenge. Does it seem like I'm on the right track? Are there better libraries than Nokogiri for doing something like this? Or, is it even possible for me to make this work?

Comment: I recommend mechanize.  It wraps up the Nokogiri and HTML into a neat package with a more "web-browser-like" API.

Comment: Rather than scraping, if it's for research purposes, and if you're in school, can't you find a way to contact the owners of the site and get more direct access to the images, perhaps via FTP? For a legitimate purpose it seems like access would be granted. If not, look at the page using a browser, without JavaScript enabled. Each image name is right there, and easily accessible via Nokogiri searches. Figure out the full path to the image directory, add that image name, and you should be able to access them using OpenURI.

Comment: Mechanize would require a bit of extra work as it doesn't execute JavaScript. You'll need to deconstruct the JavaScript (it just fills in a couple of hidden form fields before posting the form), but another option is to use a browser driver like Watir or Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using Mark Thomas's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928150/scraping-a-database-of-images-with-ruby#comment24480045_16928150) of Selenium, which works wonderfully. Thanks!